# How come all my seaborn plots melt into one plot?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, legend, spyder

I need 8 separate graphs. Is there a way to do this without using `#%%` and clicking 8 times?

I do this

```
Nplot130317 = sns.scatterplot(x="NewID", y="Time", hue="Speed", hue_norm=(0,130), data=Ndata130317, s=2, linewidth=0) 
Nplot210317 = sns.scatterplot(x="NewID", y="Time", hue="Speed", data=Ndata210317, s=2, linewidth=0)
Nplot290317 = sns.scatterplot(x="NewID", y="Time", hue="Speed", data=Ndata290317, s=2, linewidth=0)
Nplot060417 = sns.scatterplot(x="NewID", y="Time", hue="Speed", data=Ndata060417, s=2, linewidth=0)
Iplot130317 = sns.scatterplot(x="NewID", y="Time", hue="Speed", data=Idata130317_2, s=10, linewidth=0)
Iplot210317 = sns.scatterplot(x="NewID", y="Time", hue="Speed", data=Idata210317_2, s=10, linewidth=0)
Iplot290317 = sns.scatterplot(x="NewID", y="Time", hue="Speed", data=Idata290317_2, s=10, linewidth=0)
Iplot060417 = sns.scatterplot(x="NewID", y="Time", hue="Speed", data=Idata060417_2, s=10, linewidth=0)
```

And this happens:

[image: Plot]

Comment: Add`plt.show()` after each `sns.scatterplot()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to create a set of axes/subplots and specify the `ax` parameter for each call to `seaborn.scatterplot`. Per the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html),

> **ax** : ***matplotlib Axes, optional***
>   Axes object to draw the plot onto, otherwise uses the current Axes.

In the question code this could be done as

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 4, figsize=(16,6))
Nplot130317 = sns.scatterplot(x="NewID", y="Time", hue="Speed", data=Ndata130317, ax=axs[0,0]) 
Nplot210317 = sns.scatterplot(x="NewID", y="Time", hue="Speed", data=Ndata210317, ax=axs[0,1])
Nplot290317 = sns.scatterplot(x="NewID", y="Time", hue="Speed", data=Ndata290317, ax=axs[0,2])
Nplot060417 = sns.scatterplot(x="NewID", y="Time", hue="Speed", data=Ndata060417, ax=axs[0,3])
Iplot130317 = sns.scatterplot(x="NewID", y="Time", hue="Speed", data=Idata130317_2, ax=axs[1,0])
Iplot210317 = sns.scatterplot(x="NewID", y="Time", hue="Speed", data=Idata210317_2, ax=axs[1,1])
Iplot290317 = sns.scatterplot(x="NewID", y="Time", hue="Speed", data=Idata290317_2, ax=axs[1,2])
Iplot060417 = sns.scatterplot(x="NewID", y="Time", hue="Speed", data=Idata060417_2, ax=axs[1,3])
```